# How can I get the stack trace in Specman?

Tags: stack-trace, callstack, specman

Is there any way to get the stack trace in Specman?  I patched the functions that force signals to tell me *when* signals are forced.  I want to be able to tell *where* the forcing originated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_stack_trace()
```

It is beautiful.  I only wish I could extend the 'assert' construct so it always prints out a stack-trace like python...

btw, this method can take multiple seconds to evaluate.  You don't want to do print_stack_trace() unless you need to or you've hit an assertion.